# can't find executable rails for rails-3.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When trying to run 'rails s' I get the following error?

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:334:in `bin_path': can't find executable rails for rails-3.2.6 (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/bin/rails:19

I am using RVM and I am sure I installed it in the incorrect location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install via RVM, then, that message will never appear, because it's the message emitted by the ruby which come with OS X, which probably invoked by /usr/bin/rails.

I guess you installed RVM and ruby, but not rails via RVM. Assuming you're using 1.9.3-p194, you must:

```
% rvm 1.9.3-p194
```

then, run

```
% gem install rails
```

now, run `which rails`, It should show the rails's path somehere beneath `~/.rvm`. in my case:

```
% which rails
/Users/shigeya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails
```

If it is not, check your path variable. You may also re-login to set `PATH` correctly, if you just installed ruby and RVM.

Answer (score 0):

The above worked and I also did the following (exactly no misspellings):

```
rvmsudo gem install rails
rvmsudo gem install bundler
rvmsudo rubygems current

rvm gemset create rails31
rvm use 1.9.3p194@rails31 --default
rvm --rvmrc --create use 1.9.3-p194@uxolo
```